# How to update svn working copy via a cron when svn server is located on local server

Tags: linux, svn, cron, cronjob

I have two servers. One of them has a svn server running and another hosting projects.

I have a daily cronjob updating the projects -- ie running svn update, rebuild etc.

Now, my cronjob on the remote server works. 
However, a similar cronjob running on the local server for local projects (ie the same server as svn) is instead displaying a "svn: not working copy".

I double checked the paths, permissions and user info and if the script is launched manually, it works fine. 
Deploying the same thing remotely works.

I even tried using file:///  (suggested here http://www.hightekhosting.com.au/myaccount/knowledgebase/90/Using-SubversionorSVN-on-cPanel-Servers.html) but still nothing.

Please advise,

Thanks,

-hbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an environment difference between your local shell and the environment created by the cronjob.

Create this script in `/tmp/env-test`:

```
#!/bin/bash

env
echo $PATH
type -a svn
cd /path/to/local/workarea
svn info
```

Make it executable, run it manually then put it into cron with its output saved:

```
1  11  *  *  *  /tmp/env-test 2>1 >/tmp/cron-env
```

Compare the output of the local run and the cron version.

My hunch is that there's something different in your PATH.

Comment: Thank you!
I exported the path to my cronjob and it worked.